# python runs fine at local but doesn't not run at deployoment with heroku

Tags: git, heroku, plotly-dash, heroku-cli

I am having an issue while deploying my app at heroku.
I have followed tutorials including dash tutorial and some others but still I cannot find out what I am doing wrong.
Step by step I do this:

1. create a virtual env (using pipenv) during my deployment
2. after code is correct I run all repositories as should it be done (`freeze >requirements.txt`) and lock my requirements etc...
3. move to GIT and here is something I have not seen anayone to do: I use LFS because I have some code from MATLAB with large dataset which my app loads.
4. I don't use CLI to deploy heroku becuase of the push limitations with lfs, so instead I link my GIThub repository directly at heroku website.
5. manually deploy the branch.

After this heroku is happy and deploys my app but when I go to the webdeployed something wrong happens. I tried to update dinos but it is also not ok.

Here is my github repository if someone would like to try to deploy it: `https://github.com/jmbruges/pcV3.git`

this is the log errors I get:

---

```
019-05-08T08:17:37.782961+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user javier.bruges@miun.se

2019-05-08T08:18:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

2019-05-08T08:18:16.420769+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=pc-poincare-v3.herokuapp.com request_id=7e0bcbda-7e0a-4044-bad3-93b0c3032b2b fwd="193.10.110.224" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2019-05-08T08:20:14.395096+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `heroku ps:scale web=1` by user javier.bruges@miun.se

2019-05-08T08:20:26.411807+00:00 heroku[run.1831]: State changed from starting to up

2019-05-08T08:20:26.213707+00:00 heroku[run.1831]: Awaiting client

2019-05-08T08:20:26.516875+00:00 heroku[run.1831]: Starting process with command `heroku ps:scale web=1`

2019-05-08T08:20:30.827949+00:00 heroku[run.1831]: State changed from up to complete

2019-05-08T08:20:30.809159+00:00 heroku[run.1831]: Process exited with status 127

2019-05-08T08:58:32.680284+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=pc-poincare-v3.herokuapp.com request_id=03606f5e-1d4c-42a8-8f5e-a4ae7a051958 fwd="193.10.110.224" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
```

Comment: Why are you doing `pip freeze > requirements.txt` if you're using Pipenv?

Comment: As I understand the pip freeze will consolidate all my dependencies (packages) inside the text file so I can provide during the deployment. If not I will need to go to the pipenv shell location to find all the packages I am using in the virtual environment. Just a way to save it locally, or?

Comment: You already have `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`, right?

Comment: yes I have those. I actually found another solution to the problem thanks to a colleague. The idea is to use Flask to embed the app, so flask will be deployed in the server encapsulating the app, so after calling flask app, this will be the one that renders the data.

Comment: BTW, @Chris, to answer again, the [Pipfile] and Pipfile.lock are available at the GIT repo I published.

Comment: If you have `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` you don't need `requirements.txt`. They serve roughly the same purpose for different tools.

Comment: Thank you! I just learned that thanks to your comment. Requirements can be useful but for importing other older repositories to my new virtual env.

Comment: I don't know your exact use case, but generally speaking each application should have its own virtual environment. When you talk about importing other repositories into your new virtualenv I worry that you're packing multiple codebases into a single environment.

Comment: Honestly I am new into python. This is how I work if I start a new folder with a new jupyter-notebook:
1- create folder
2- create an empty shell (run pipenv install and later shell)
3- open jupyter notebook
4- install the pack using pipenv
If I have to clone a repo I have before to start some new development:
1- copy the folder containing the pipfile and piplock
2- run pipenv shell which will open a new env with the prexisting env
3- run pipenv update to be sure all pack are available
4- start working
What do you think?